# Terminology and notation for asymptotic expansion

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have a theory that gives me a series expansion for some function $f(x;\lambda)$, assuming large $\lambda$, in the form
$$f(x;\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n(x)}{\lambda^n}.$$

I claimed that $f(x;\lambda)=c_0+c_1/\lambda+O(\lambda^{-2}),$
but someone told me I was confusing "the $O(\cdot)$ asymptotic Landau-notation with a perturbative expansion" and that "convergence only holds weakly".

I am not sure what this means.

My question is exactly what terminology and notation I should use in this case.

Comment: For instance, should I say "$f(x;\lambda)\sim c_0+c_1/\lambda$"? What exactly is the difference between this and "$f(x;\lambda)= c_0+c_1/\lambda+O(\lambda^{-2})$"?

Comment: Use the notation just as it is written for example in Murdock's classical book.